# Co-registration issue for the Landsat collection 2 level 1 products

Tags: landsat, coregistration

While browsing through the Landsat image product, I come across an issue.
The below images are two Landsat 1 scenes (**Landsat collection 2 level 1**).

[image]

The problem is in the overlapping part of the images.

[image]

I think the images are not co-registering correctly. But the same tiles in **Landsat collection 1 level 1** don't show any problems.

The below images are two Landsat 1 scenes (**Landsat collection 1 level 1**).

[image]

The overlapping part.

[image]

What is the problem here? I want to use the collection 2 level 1 product as I have used the same collection for other Landsat series images. **So how to solve this issue for Landsat collection 1 level 2?**

*The details of the images are,*

*Satellite: Landsat 1, Dates (path, row): 1973-01-18 (Path: 150, Row: 46) and 1973-01-17 (Path: 149, Row: 46)*